# django form data to pdf or A4 paper

Tags: django

Is it possible to design an A4 paper and create a form in which the user fills in information in the form on the site and django converts the information to the paper that you designed previously and prints it?

Comment: Maybe there are some hidden aspects I did not catched, but I do not seen any issue to define a form and, when the user posts it, define data to be store in pdf format consistent with an A4 print. This will be done in python at the backend side (in a view or as a method model, according to your context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can get the form data and use weasyprint (for example) to render the PDF: https://pypi.org/project/weasyprint/